Snap7 and Modbus
I want to connect Python to PLC siemens. I have searched about snap7 and modbus but what is more popular when people use in project and what protocol is more stable?
I have tried both protocols and one thing I realise is that using Modbus require a little bit complicate in TIA Portal, which snap7 is more easier.

so what is the actual question here ?

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
